# Chef knife command not showing ssl subcommands

Tags: ruby, ssl, chef-infra, knife

There is no `knife ssl ...` subcommand. It seems indicated that it's part and parcel of a ChefDK + knife distro but I'm unsure why it's not available.

What should I do to get the ssl subcommands available to knife?

chef-client -version
Chef: 11.6.2

```
$ knife

...

** SEARCH COMMANDS **
knife search INDEX QUERY (options)

** SHOW COMMANDS **
knife show [PATTERN1 ... PATTERNn]

** SSH COMMANDS **
knife ssh QUERY COMMAND (options)

** STATUS COMMANDS **
knife status QUERY (options)

** TAG COMMANDS **
knife tag create NODE TAG ...
knife tag delete NODE TAG ...
knife tag list NODE

....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those commands were added in Chef 11.12.0. Please install a newer version of ChefDK which will include an updated version of Chef.